# Modify dict values inplace

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming

I would like to apply a function to values of a `dict` inplace in the `dict` (like `map` in a functional programming setting).

Let's say I have this `dict`:

```py
d = { 'a':2, 'b':3 }
```

I want to apply the function `divide by 2.0` to all values of the dict, leading to:

```py
d = { 'a':1., 'b':1.5 }
```

What is the simplest way to do that?

I use *Python 3*.

**Edit:**
A one-liner would be nice. The `divide by 2` is just an example, I need the function to be a parameter.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You may find multiply is still faster than dividing

```
d2 = {k: v * 0.5 for k, v in d.items()}
```

For an inplace version

```
d.update((k, v * 0.5) for k,v in d.items())
```

For the general case

```
def f(x)
    """Divide the parameter by 2"""
    return x / 2.0

d2 = {k: f(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: You really think multiplying will be significantly faster than dividing? Maybe in PyPy, where all of the costs but the arithmetic are shrunk down to the point where it makes a difference, but in CPython, I'll bet you can't even detect the difference…

Comment: Also, I think passing the dict comprehension to `d2` instead of a generator expression generating tuples may be more readable in this case (even if it does "wastefully" create a new dictionary).

Comment: As a side note, I don't actually like dict comprehensions in python3.x code for a two main reasons -- **1)**  Your code isn't backward compatible with python2.6, **2)** dict comprehensions look just a little bit too similar to set comprehensions.  (I also don't really like set literals for the same reason)

Comment: `%timeit` results. CPython 2.7.2: 1.11us vs. 1.12us, or 222us vs. 223us for a large (1000-item random) dictionary. CPython 3.3.0: 785ns vs. 778ns, or 160us vs. 158us. So, multiplying is not faster than dividing, as I suspected. (I haven't tested PyPy yet because I broke my `ipython-pypy`…)

Comment: OK, fixed… PyPy 1.9.0: 309ns vs. 329ns, or 94.4us vs. 94.8us. So, with PyPy, with tiny dictionaries, multiplying is slightly faster. With CPython, or with non-tiny dictionaries, they're equivalent.

Comment: @mgilson: I love dict comprehensions. Set literals are a different story, but only because `{}` is not the empty set, which is about as big an irregularity as you can have in a set display format…

Comment: @abarnert, well I started by saying "You may find..." :)

Answer (score 19):

You can loop through the keys and update them:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    d[key] = value / 2
```

Comment: This could be a 1-liner as well (if you cheat a little) -- `for key,value in d.items(): d[key] = value/2`

Comment: I don't think explicitly using `items` and `value` in this case is saving anything in readability (or performance, if that matters); Ishpeck's answer looks simpler (except for your better variable name).

Comment: @mgilson: If Guido suggests it, it doesn't count as cheating, right? (Of course he suggests it as "If you must have it on one line…")

Comment: @abarnert -- Apparently guido also once tweeted that [you can use triple-quoted strings as a block comment](https://twitter.com/gvanrossum/status/112670605505077248) ... Apparently I don't agree with him on *everything*

Comment: @mgilson: Of course not. But when he agrees with you, he's always right! That's the beauty of authority. :)

Comment: @Mic: That's really kind of misleading, if you understand what `dict.update` does. You have to figure out that the generator expression is effectively generating a lazy dictionary with the exact same keys as the original before you realize that it's changing each value in-place, while with `for key in d: d[key] /= 2` it's immediately apparent what you're doing.

Answer (score 9):

Should work for you:

```
>>> d = {'a':2.0, 'b':3.0}
>>> for x in d:
...     d[x]/=2
... 
>>> d
{'a': 1.0, 'b': 1.5}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> d = { 'a': 2, 'b': 3 }
>>> {k: v / 2.0 for k, v in d.items()}
{'a': 1.0, 'b': 1.5}
```

Comment: This creates a new dictionary right? So with a huge `dict`, it would be resource intensive. Is there a way to just modify the values without losing the advantage of having the already built `dict`? (hence the `inplace` in my question)

Comment: @Mic Don't worry about performance unless there is a performance problem (and I'm not saying there isn't, but *justify* the assertion) - or keeping the same object is required for other semantic reasons. That being said, I entirely agree with jamylak - "inplace" (mutating) and "functional" (immutable) are fairly orthogonal, depending on where the line is drawn.

Comment: @Mic True but when I heard the word 'functional' I didn't think you would tell me this.

Comment: This'll work in python2.7 also other than maybe doing integer division sometimes (which is easily fixed with a judiciously placed period).

Comment: Note that you could also do `d.update((k,v/2.) for k,v in d.items())` if you wanted it in-place.

Comment: @mgilson You can submit that if you want, I don't really like it that much

Comment: You should also note in the answer that this creates a new list , and there is little reason not to create a new list.  This is what I would do , but this doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: @JonathanVanasco There are no new lists being created

Comment: @mgilson: I think `d.update({k: v/2.0 for k, v in d.items()})` is more readable (and more obviously related to jamylak's answer).

Comment: sorry, i meant dict.  your answer creates a new one and leaves the original one intact.

Comment: and now the question has been edited so there is a d2, not the origina `d`.  so nevermind, though the question title should be changed.

Comment: @abarnert -- Yes, but I thought that OP was trying to save memory for one reason or another...

Comment: @abarnert Then you would be creating a new dictionary so you may as well use my method... mgilson's one has the benefit of using a generator

Comment: Anyway, I don't really think I would use that.  That's why I made it a comment rather than an answer.  (I prefer the for loop).

Comment: @mgilson: I agree. Paraphrasing Guido off python-ideas: If you want mutating code, write it explicit with for. If you must have it in one line, just put the body after the colon.

Comment: @mgilson indeed, I can't have two copies of this dict or my VM basically dies. Hence the `inplace` in the title.

Comment: @Mic: Are you sure that's really a problem? And, if so, why did you tag this "functional-programming"?