# Change keys order in dict in Python 3.7+

Tags: python, python-3.x

Since `dict` object has native key order in Python 3.7+ (https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html), there should be a way to manage the order. Is there an official documentation where I could read about it?

In my particular case I want to solve such issues **without creating a new dictionary**.

1. Add a new key-value pair to the beginning.
2. Sort the records in a dictionary by keys.

For the first one:

```
dct = {'b': 5, 'c': 6}
dct['a'] = 4  # What should be here
print(dct)  # I want it to be {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}
```

For the second one:

```
dct = {'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'a': 4}
dct.sort_somehow('...')  # What should be here
print(dct)  # I want it to be {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}
```

Comment: The "native key order" is retaining *insertion* order, so you can't manage it.

Comment: Per the link you linked, dictionaries retain insertion order. There is no way to change it without making a new one.

Comment: So there is not way to reorder the keys without creating a new one?

Comment: No. Why is it an issue that you can't make a new one? Why do you need sort-in-place? Why do you even need a sorted dict (since many languages don't even offer an ordered k/v data structure) in the first place? The question is still a valid question without any of that data, but it's answer is a deflating "no you can't do that". We can probably help you better if you tell us what problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: Well, the insertion order is preserved using an additional array somewhere. So theoretically you should be able to change that order, you'll just probably need to fiddle around with some dll written in c. But if you want to push an element in front of the array, it is a lot of swap operations so you are probably better off just reallocating the dict.

Comment: There's also [python - Modify dict values inplace - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536623/modify-dict-values-inplace)  if you have to mutate the dict in place for some reasons.

Comment: @user202729 I have tried. Not working.

Comment: @user202729 `dct.update(sorted([(k, v) for k, v in dct.items()]))` (for the second issue I mentioned).

Comment: Python `dict` always followed some order. then intentional randomness was introduced, but finally it is though to keep the ordering. I think it is not like managing the order, it is because of the underlining way how dictionary are implemented. There is a great pycon talk solely on python dict by Raymond Hettinger, chek it out.

Comment: @user202729 The approach with `clear` helped. Thank you! If you provide the full answer below, I will vote.

Comment: It's still a weird thing to do.

Comment: [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) has the [`move_to_end`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.move_to_end) method and with `last=False` argument it inserts at the beginning. That at least solves your first issue

Comment: @user202729 I don't find it weird. It satisfies the condition I asked. You did reorder the dictionary. :)

Comment: Anyway, generally it's a waste of time to get into the XY problem, while the problem is solvable this time, you should explain what you need this for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to mutate the dict in-place, it's possible to use `.clear()` to clear it, then `.update` to put the new values in.

```py
>>> dct = {'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'a': 4}
>>> sorted_key_values = sorted(dct.items())
>>> dct.clear()
>>> dct.update(sorted_key_values)
>>> dct
{'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}
```

Note that this still consumes the amount of memory proportional to the number of key/value in the dict. It's very hard or impossible to sort it in-place (as in not using any extra memory), see [python - Sort dict in-place - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61645769/sort-dict-in-place/61645802#61645802).

Comment: The approach is also mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692917/altering-all-keys-of-a-dictionary/49693014#49693014 , and it's claimed to be faster (and actually works this time) than updating the keys one by one.

Comment: Huh, turns out the solution is already mentioned in the **body** of the question linked above.